# Angular component input with dynamic id and name not working

Tags: angular, property-binding

I have the following list of components, which take an `id` and `label` value as properties.

```html
<ul>
   <li>
     <btn-attatch
      id="one"
      label="label1"
      (file)="specialFileType($event)"
      >
      </btn-attatch>
   </li>
   <li>
      <btn-attatch
       id="two"
       label="label2"
       (file)="specialFileType($event)"
      >
      </btn-attatch>
   <li>
</ul>
```

Inside my component I set the following template and values accordingly:

```html
 <input
  type="file"
  [attr.name]="id"
  [attr.id]="id"
  (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)"
  class="inputfile"
  />
  <label *ngIf="!fileName" [attr.for]="id">{{ label }}</label>
```

```js
  private _id: string;
  @Input() set id(s: string) {
    this._id = s;
  }
  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  private _label: string;
  @Input() set label(s: string) {
    this._label = s;
  }
  get label() {
    return this._label;
  }
```

*My issue* is that when i am setting fixed values in the input and label inside the component , as opposed to sending in those values via @Input, everything works. Once I try to dynamicaly set the id and labels via @Input, the input becomes unclickable.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by changing the input attribute name from **id** to **identifier**.

That is, `@Input() id => @Input() identifier`

It seems that Angular will get confused when parsing the id attribute on a component.

By the way, I implemented the ControlValueAccessor Interface for my customised component.